# Mysql Azure is not connecting with the Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, azure

I tried to migrate from mysql localhost database to mysql azure database in Laravel. So, I changed the environment variables (.env) as this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database.mysql.database.azure.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myquery_use
DB_USERNAME=database
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

However, when I tried to migrate a table into the system, the error like above appear. What should I fix so the laravel and mysql azure are connected?

```
  PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user 'database'@'121' for table 'migrations'")
          C:\xampp\htdocs\system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant privileges for the user before it can create the table. Not all MySql users will have permission to do this but the root user should do.

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myquery_use`.* TO 'database'@'localhost'
```

You may also need to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES after for changes effect.

Comment: Where should I put that script in my code? *Im not really familiar with the command

Comment: Run it on your database client as the root user